# Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined while bootstrap is working fine

Tags: jquery

Hi I'm probably missing something very stupid here, but why does Twitter Bootstrap working fine, but my code throughs this error as if it cannot find the jQuery library?

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've got a typo - your script elements say `scr="..."` instead of `src="..."`.

The incorrect attribute will be ignored, so you're left with a (blank) inline script, and jQuery isn't loaded.

Comment: OMG :) As I've said - something stupid was missing. Thanks!

Comment: Just realized that TB's css was working only. TB's js wasn't working for the same reason.

Comment: @AlexOkrushko yeah, I did wonder about that.